# Please welcome your new moderator, Zaralynda!

Tags: discussion, moderators

While I'm sad to report the venerable Ashley Nunn stepping down as one of your moderators due to time and life constraints, it brings me great pleasure to announce that [Zaralynda](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/224/zaralynda) has volunteered to step up and take Ashley's place.

Many of you probably know Zaralynda just through interactions on the site, but if not:

[image: profile for Zaralynda at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

Showing all of the same great traits that go into a fantastic moderator, I'm certain that Zaralynda will be a great addition to the team. Please give a warm welcome and remember - we're all learning here.

Welcome, Zaralynda! It's great to have you on board.

Comment: Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for the warm welcome, and thank you Ashley Nunn for serving as our moderator for the first several months of the site!

Comment: You are, of course, somewhat insane as a consequence of this decision. I should know. ;D

Comment: Congratulations to you, and best wishes for some well-deserved rest for Ashley!

Comment: Replacing a cat person with a cat person fills the cat-shaped void in site moderation.